# Finding if $\frac{-yi+xj}{x^2+y^2}$ is a conservative field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\frac{s}{r}$ be a vector field such that: $s=-yi+xj,r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

> Is $\frac{s}{r}$ a conservative field?

**My attempt:**

$\frac{s}{r}$ is a conservative field $\iff \displaystyle\oint F\cdot dr=0$

$$\frac{s}{r}=\frac{-y\hat i+x\hat j}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$\boxed{=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot \hat i+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot \hat j }$$

Let $Q:=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ , let $P:=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

$\frac{s}{r}$ is a conservative field $\iff \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$

Finding $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$: $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y)^{3/2}}}$

Finding $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$: $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=-\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y)^{3/2}}}$

$\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$  therfore $\frac{s}{r}$ is not conservative field.

> Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to show that a particular vector field is not conservative is to take the line integral around a closed loop and see that the result is not zero.

For your field, taking the line integral around the unit circle gives a value of $2\pi$, so the field is not conservative. In fact, your field and that line integral are (almost) the examples [given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields) for a non-conservative field.